# How to indicate to the end of file in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, binaryfiles

I have a flat file saved in binary format, i want to seek to specific byte and read untile the end of that file, so we need a condition for that, what is the condition that indicates the end of the file?

By the way, i don't want to load the whole file just open the file and seek to the position i need then read until to the end of the file...

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB's `fread` function (and, indeed, the other file IO functions) will automatically detect the end of a binary file; there's no need for a special end-of-file marker.

[fread documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/fread.html)

[General MATLAB IO documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/tech-notes/1600/1602.html)

Comment: As an addition to Sam's answer you can check the Matlab function [`feof`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/feof.html) that tests for the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [feof](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/feof.html) to test for the end of a file. For example, to read a file one character at a time:

```
fid = fopen('bench.dat');

k = 0;
while ~feof(fid)
    curr = fscanf(fid,'%c',1);
    if ~isempty(curr)
       k = k+1;
       benchstr(k) = curr;
    end
end

fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `Inf` for the size argument when using the [FREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fread.html) function (will read until end of file). Here is an example:

```
%# first lets create a simple binary file
fid = fopen('file.bin', 'wb');
fwrite(fid, 'hello world', 'char*1');
fclose(fid);

%# now open binary file, seek to some position, and read bytes till EOF
fid = fopen('file.bin', 'rb');
fseek(fid, 6, 'bof');                %# go to the 7th byte
B = fread(fid, Inf, 'uint8=>char');  %# read bytes until end-of-file (as chars)
fclose(fid);

disp(B)
```

Comment: you are right, but FYI fseek function will seek to the position in (bit) not in byte...

but see what i relly want? i have 2 files, i want to read for example 1000 byte, so from the first file it should read from the end of file for example from byte 500 till the last(not all time but sometimes depend on what user specify), so if what it read less than 1000, it should go to the next file and complete the rest bytes... so in this case how can i do it?

Comment: actually [FSEEK](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fseek.html) does offset in **bytes** not bits (just read the documentation page)... As for you other question, you can simply check the length of the data read from the first file, subtract the count from 1000, and read that many bytes left from the second.